# Linking to a chat room via XMPP: URI

Tags: pidgin, dbus, xmpp, uri

I found out how to link directly to a chat room on a Jabber conference server -- it took a bit of digging, and I wound up actually looking at the spec before I was sure I was doing it right.  I confirmed [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisg/entry/pidgin_url_handler_and_xmpp), so I'm pretty sure I've got it.

The results, though, are puzzling.  If I click a link of the style `xmpp:dude@example.com` I get a new chat session with user "dude" at example.com, as expected.  If I tack on a nonsense query (`xmpp:dude@example.com?foobar`), it's ignored, which is what the spec says should happen.  However, if I use `xmpp:room@conference.example.com?join`, as in the link above, nothing happens.

I dug a little deeper, and found out that on my (Linux) system, xmpp URIs are handled via `purple-url-handler`, so I dropped to a terminal and ran it manually.  The result was that any xmpp URI ran fine *except* one that includes a ?join query.  The ?join query results in a dbus crash, pointing specifically to line 2356 of dbus-message.c -- a little Googling suggests this probably is dbus's less-than-elegant way of telling me that somebody is using dbus incorrectly.

Am I crafting my link correctly?  Is this an OS or maybe application issue?  Does this work on other platforms / browsers / etc?  More importantly, is there any easy way to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URI scheme used by XMPP is defined in [XEP-0147](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0147.html) and extended for `?join` in [XEP-0045, point 15.7.2.](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#registrar-querytypes-join) In this form it is handled f.e. by `psi` and `gajim` -- so this standard is already being implemented by some XMPP clients.

I guess that if your software crashes in such a simple scenario, your software is buggy. You should report that to your distribution maintainers.

Comment: Now I just have to hunt down the bugtracker / maintainer for "purple-url-handler" and... wait?

Comment: @Coderer, Welcome in the open source world. That seems to be a standard route. If you want to fix it by yourself, you could try also checking packages from unstable/next release of your distribution.